# How to stop continuous execution of while loop with same connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am making a server for a Chat application in Java.

The while loop is supposed to connect to new clients but the code keeps connecting to the first client repeatedly even after it has connected resulting in Bind Failed error. What should I change?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServerM
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Listener l = new Listener();
            l.run();
        }
    }

}

class Listener implements Runnable
{
    static InetAddress arr[] = new InetAddress[10];
    static int i = 0;

    public void run()
    {

        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(44444);
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected!\n");

            DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String ip = din.readUTF();

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);

            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                if(arr[j] == addr)
                    return;
            }

            arr[i++] = addr;

            ChatThread c = new ChatThread(addr,s);//This creates a thread to allow communication with Client
            c.run();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the design of the solution. You are running a multiple instances of the Server Socket (and using the same port, what will end in an exception) and using this thread for getting the client connections, therefore you can only have one connection.

What you should do is, run a Thread for the Server Socket who will listen for all the connections, and then run every client instance (new Thread) in an infinite loop.

```
public class ServerM
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Listener l = new Listener();
        l.run();

    }

}

class Listener implements Runnable
{
    static InetAddress arr[] = new InetAddress[10];
    static int i = 0;

    public void run()
    {

        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(44444);
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            while (true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                ClientListener clientListener = new ClientListener(s);
                clientListener.run();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ClientListener implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    public ClientListener(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Connected!\n");

        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        String ip = din.readUTF();

        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);

        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] == addr)
                return;
        }

        arr[i++] = addr;

        ChatThread c = new ChatThread(addr,socket);
        c.run();
    }

}
```

You have to do this because you only need one instance of ServerSocket listening for new connections at a specific port, and then you need [1..n] client instances for handling each connection.

Answer (score 0):

Catch Exception is bad practice

```
 catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try to forward an custom exception (MyException.class) to the top level and handle this exception in ServerM class in try..catch. And don't forget to close socket in finally block

```
ss.close();
s.close();
```